# file type was not found when using LineChart in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, charts

I am using FlashDevelop to develop flex applications and wanted to paint a LineChart in a panel. I used an example of Adobe itself to be found [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/charts/LineChart.html#includeExamplesSummary).

When I compiled it FlashDevelop showed the following output

```
file type was not found or was not a compile-time constant
```

For Both LineChart and AreaChart.

Can someone tell me why this happens? I also tried it in the code by importing mx.charts.LineChart, my code completion found the classes but when compiling the same error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered by bug-a-lot the Data Visualization classes and components that Adobe creates are licensed separately and must be downloaded separately from the SDK.

You can download the Flex 3.3 components here ->

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex3sdk

Note however that if you use them you will get a watermark in any of the charting components.  To get rid of this watermark you have to have a Flex Builder Pro license.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Adobe Flex Data Visualization Components along with the Flex SDK you are using.